# GWT OverlayTypes Date and Long

Tags: java, gwt, types, overlay

I have some errors from Date and Long types and Overlay Types. Both uses long which is not allowed in GWT JSNI. Date serializes as long via getTime().

What I am doing right now (and it seems to work) is:

FROM JAVA (Using Jackson to serialize to json)

```
Long myLong = new Long(50)
Date myDate = new Date();

public String getMyLong()
{
return String.valueOf(myLong);
}

public String getDate() {
return String.valueOf(date.getTime());
}
```

FROM GWT (Using OverlayTypes)

```
/*Returning a Long*/
private final native String _getEscaletaId()   /*-{ return this.escaletaId; }-*/; 
public final Long getEscaletaId() {return new Long(_getEscaletaId());}
/*Returning a Date*/
private final native String _getDate() /*-{ return this.date; }-*/; 
public final Date getDate() {return new Date(Long.valueOf(_getDate()));}
```

Is this the better approach to deal with long and other special types?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dates, there's [`JsDate`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/core/client/JsDate.html), a thin JSO wrapper around the JS [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) object.

Longs are dicey because JavaScript doesn't have the concept of a long. All numbers are 53-bit doubles, a fact which [bit Twitter recently](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/6a16efa375532182).

Comment: Thankyou! I didn't know about JsDate. What is GWT doing with Long emulation? Can I handle a big number with Long emulation the way I'm doing?

Comment: GWT emulates longs as a pair of numbers, which means they will work, but they will also be inefficient. As a result, use ints or doubles whenever possible. More info here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html

Comment: And additionally: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#important for some suggested workarounds.